# Using cpanm module in Ansible

Tags: perl, ansible

This is my first time using the cpanm module in Ansible. I am trying to pull from their search engine a specific module, MIME::QuotedPrint and can't seem to get it to pull using my Ansible script. Can someone take a look and let me know what I am doing wrong here?

```
- name: Downloading Perl Modules
  cpanm: name=MIME::QuotedPrint mirror=http://search.cpan.org/CPAN/authors/id/J/JH/JHI/perl-5.8.0.tar.gz
```

I checked Ansible documentation but I'm not sure what the alias/pkg name is as mentioned. Thanks all!!

Comment: `cpanm` is not maintaining a search engine. It's not affiliated with metacpan.org (sounds like you thought so). It is just a neat client that works with any CPAN mirror.

Comment: Thanks for that info! is there a way to use cpanm to pull QuotedPrint correctly? Or am i going about this the wrong way altogether?

Comment: The mirror is wrong. A cpan mirror is a server that has a full copy of the CPAN, but you put an actual distribution release there. It looks like it's the release for Perl itself, in version 5.8.0. Do you care which CPAN mirror you are going to use? Maybe one that's physically close to you? At $work we do that because our company provides a public CPAN mirror, so we use it as it's closer and thus faster. But you don't have to. On the command line you would do `cpanm MIME::QuotedPrint` and that's it. Not sure about how to get Ansible to do that. Maybe `cmd`? I haven't used Ansible recently.

Comment: Ok cool. I also know that cpanm is not installed on the remote server.. Looks like that needs to be done in order for me to use the cpanm module in Ansible...thanks for your help :-)

Comment: Why not just use `cpan`? You could also bootstrap `cpanm` directly in your Ansbile script. See [here](https://metacpan.org/pod/App::cpanminus#Installing-to-local-perl-(perlbrew,-plenv-etc.)). You can also abuse that to install anything else with the bootstrap version. But only do that if you feel it's save to run arbitrary code off the internet that you don't really control.

Comment: Well i was originally looking for a cpan module in Ansible (i have a few modules i need to download). I found cpanm instead. But i actually found a way to use the cpanm module correctly and got it working

Comment: Great. Please post your solution as an answer so others can benefit. You can accept it tomorrow too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a nice work around for this:

```
- name: Installing CPANM
  command: cpan install App::cpaminus

- name: Downloading Perl Modules
  cpanm: name=MIME::QuotedPrint
```

This got it to work correctly.

Comment: Most Linux distributions provide cpanm as a package, so you can always install that using e.g. the apt or dnf Ansible module before using the cpanm Ansible module.

Comment: And you don't need `install`. From the command line cpan just takes module names. There is a package named _install_ on CPAN that does nothing because lots of people do this wrong and removing it would break everyone's stuff.

Comment: the cpan install App::cpaminus did not work for me, either in an ansible task or on the command line.

Answer (score 3):

That is very close.  Here is that solution, improved:

```
- name: Installing CPANM
  yum: pkg=perl-App-cpanminus

- name: Downloading Perl Modules
  cpanm: name=MIME::QuotedPrint
```

This uses the best of Ansible's checks to avoid re-installing cpanm every time. Per the comments above, change the whole `yum` line there to `apt` or `dnf` based on your flavor of Linux, and the package name may differ too.